Need help to replace a switch in C#
I have a console application in .NET 6 that receives one argument, and based on that, has to decide which operation will be executed. At first, I had all the operations as static methods and everything being decided in a big switch statement, but then I refactored the action executions.
But now I'm still trying to figure out how to remove the switch statement in order for everything to become a bit more dynamic and not worrying about adding a new case, each time a new action is developed.
Basically trying to reach a solution (at least a "good" approach) were the developer should only worry about the coding of the action class itself and not going to the switch (the program should know what relates to what -> argument-to-action)
At the moment the main code is something as follows:
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // validating args
            if (!args.Any())
                return;

            switch (args.First())
            {
                case "action1":
                case "action2":
                case "action3":
                    break;

                default:
                    return;
            }

            switch (args.First())
            {
                case "action1":
                    RunTheAction<Action1>();
                    break;

                case "action2":
                    RunTheAction<Action2>();
                    break;

                case "action3":
                    //todo RunTheAction<Action3>()
                    break;

                // it keeps growing -> RunTheAction<>()
            }
        }

        static void RunTheAction<T>() where T : IAction
        {
            var action = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            action.Execute();
        }
    }
}

All action instances to be executed use the interface IAction:
internal interface IAction
{
    void Execute();
}

internal class Action1 : IAction
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        // do some action1 stuff
    }
}

internal class Action2 : IAction
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        // do some action2 stuff (different than action1 :) )
    }
}

Constant strings relations with the actions

What I have done in the past to resolve a similar situation: Replace with a Lookup.
(where "situation" refers to having a switch/case that needed to be replaced)
var whatToDo = new Dictionary<string, Action>() {
  ["action1"] = () => Execute<Action1>(),
  ["action2"] = () => Execute<Action2>(),
};

// ...

string theActionKey = // from args ...
if (whatToDo.TryGetValue(theActionKey, out var theAction))
{
   theAction();
}
else
{
  // Handle Action not found.
}

^^ Of course, this is a very simple setup with hard-coded dictionary. You could set it up via DI, manual registration, reflection using annotations, nowadays maybe code-gen? ...
I'd still recommend to follow Anthony's answer in this specific context of the question.
I know we shouldn't but for the time of writing this, my personal recommendation would be Spectre.Console.Cli for this task.
You'll need to follow some design choices and implement the according interfaces, but you get a lot in return for that.
There, tying action keys to an implementation boils down to basically this:
var app = new CommandApp();
app.Configure(config =>
{
    config.AddCommand<AddCommand>("add");
    config.AddCommand<CommitCommand>("commit");
    config.AddCommand<RebaseCommand>("rebase");
});

Example from https://spectreconsole.net/cli/commandapp

Thanks, I went using the dictionary approach since I cannot use external libs as much as I like in the project I'm working. But also learned about the spectreConsole, thank you also for that. Cheers

Don't reinvent the wheel. CommandlineUtils  is a great library that does what you want and has great of documentation. It allows you to define command hierarchy and handles parsing parameters so you can pass data to individual commands if required. Works with dependency injection and logging so you can build professional console applications.

There are several great command line parser packages out there. There's also one from Microsoft now https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/

I've also seen Spectre.Console being used by Microsoft ... in the Upgrade Assistant

Yet, this is rather answering the Y in the X-Y Question :D

@EricJ. unfortunately the one from Microsoft is semi-abandoned: they kept changing it without releases to the point that the NuGet package is 2 years old and completely unrelated to the code in Github.
